# Django populate a listbox from a form with a raw mysql query result

Tags: mysql, django, list, forms, populate

I have a listbox in a form that is populated with a manual list :

Forms.py

```
FRUIT_CHOICES= [
    ('Oranges', 'Oranges'),
    ('Cantaloupes', 'Cantaloupes'),
    ('Mangoes', 'Mangoes'),
    ('Honeydews', 'Honeydews'),
    ]


class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    testrever = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        exclude = ("user",)
```

models.py

```
class Record(models.Model):
    testrever = models.JSONField(max_length=500)
```

html

```
{{ form.testrever }}
```

I would like to replace the `FRUIT_CHOICE`list by the result of a raw Mysql query like :

```
"SELECT * FROM website_record WHERE first_name RLIKE %s",[search]
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: This looks really like something a Django queryset could do...